# How to zoom out in gojs?

Tags: gojs

I am trying to zoom out but not's working and here I'm using **go.ForceDirectedLayout**

```
var myDiagram = $(go.Diagram, "database_structure",
    {
      "toolManager.mouseWheelBehavior": go.ToolManager.WheelZoom,
      initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.TopLeft,
      allowDelete: false,
      allowCopy: false,
      layout: $(go.ForceDirectedLayout),
      autoScale: go.Diagram.UniformToFill,
      "undoManager.isEnabled": true
    });
```

Initially it displayed empty screen after I scroll it will display the diagram.
But I want initially **zoom out the screen** so please give some solution to solve this.

After I set given below ,the diagram displayed when I scroll the mouse but I need display the diagram **without scroll in initially**.

Here I 'm using **fixedBounds:new go.Rect(-1000,-1000,1,1)** so it reduce the diagram size initially.

```
myDiagram =
    $(go.Diagram, "database_structure",
      {
      "toolManager.mouseWheelBehavior": go.ToolManager.WheelZoom,
        initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,
        layout: $(go.ForceDirectedLayout),
        fixedBounds:new go.Rect(-1000,-1000,1,1),
        initialAutoScale: go.Diagram.Uniform,
        scale:0.0001,
        "undoManager.isEnabled": true
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set **Diagram.autoScale**, which will cause it to always zoom to "UniformToFill".  That will prevent the user from doing their own zooming.

If you only want to automatically rescale the diagram "UniformToFill" when you first load the model after the initial layout, set **Diagram.initialAutoScale** instead.  This will allow the user to zoom in or out afterwards.

https://gojs.net/latest/intro/initialView.html#AutomaticViewportManagement
https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Diagram.html#initialAutoScale

Comment: Hi walter,                                                                                                            
      I set initialAutoScale: go.Diagram.UniformToFill but it fully zoom out the screen and display the blank  screen.Is there any way to set zoom out in certain limit level?

Comment: Did you check the value of **Diagram.scale** afterwards?  It seems unlikely that it would really zoom out unless there are parts scattered about a wide area (i.e. if the **Diagram.documentBounds** were very large).  Nevertheless you can limit the scale to be larger than some fixed scale by setting https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Diagram.html#minScale.

Comment: Hi walter,here I set  "toolManager.mouseWheelBehavior": go.ToolManager.WheelZoom,initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center,
            layout: $(go.ForceDirectedLayout),
            fixedBounds:new go.Rect(-1000,-1000,1,1),
            initialAutoScale: go.Diagram.Uniform,
            scale:2.005 It displayed a diagram when I scroll the mouse but i need default diagram initially without scroll so please guide me.

Comment: Don't set **Diagram.fixedBounds**.